# How to save asp.net html articles

Tags: asp.net, html, xml

I have asp.net web page on home page i want to add articles and news.

Which would be better way for saving articles store it on database or .xml or .html?

Comment: You're really looking for a CMS, did you know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store it in a good *normalized* table structure. Put different meta information in different columns and put the article as **html** in a *column*.

If you were to store it in a **file** I'd recommend saving it in **XML** so that you can save meta information along with the article. But as you are using Database, meta information can be saved in other columns. So **plain HTML is completely okay**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say for any homepage type applications, saving content in files (be it xml, html or plan text) is enough.

Scott Hanselman's blog uses dasblog, which doesn't needs a database and simply stores all contents in text files in a folder.

Answer (score -1):

Really? Thats like "what is better; a red or blue car". That said, db driven designs are more common